# Chrome Form Auto Complete Not Working

Tags: google-chrome

Data entered into textboxes is usually remembered after you enter it once. It works fine in other browsers but Chrome doesn't seem to remember.

Comment: Websites have no control over this kind of thing, so I would not consider this a programming related question.

Answer (score 0):

Click the spanner icon and select Options.

Choose the Personal Stuff tab on the left, and enable "Auto Fill".